# How do I correctly pull data from Bitbucket?

Tags: python, django, django-views, bitbucket

I have the following model:

```
class RepoDetails(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Owner, default='your repo username')
    repo_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    repo_username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    repo_password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False,  blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return ' '.join([self.repo_name, self.repo_username])
```

And in my views, I have this:

```
def get_repo_data(request):
    url = 'https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/user/'
    repositories = RepoDetails.objects.filter(owner=request.user)
    username = repositories.repo_username
    password = repositories.repo_password
    name = repositories.repo_name
    repo_data = requests.get(url, auth=(username, password)).json()
    date = get_repo_last_updated(repo_data, name=name)
    updated = repositories.updated.get_or_create(updated=date)
    # update = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.strptime(tweet['created_at'],'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y'))
    template = 'repository/repositories_status.html'
    return render(request, template, {'repo_updated': date})

def get_repo_last_updated(data, name):
    return next((d for d in data['repositories'] if d['name'] == name), {}).get('utc_last_updated')
```

I want to check the status of my repository by accessing the API, and out of the JSON, get the 'utc_last_updated' and check the date value. If it is newer than the stored updated field, then it should replace and save the latest one.

However nothing of the above seems to be working now. The username and password are the [Bitbucket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitbucket) username and password that you use.

How can I fix this problem?